# Ordenar de manera descendente una relación de una tabla

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model, relaciones

Con Eloquent estoy haciendo una petición a base de datos, donde traigo todos los datos de una tabla llamada Group y a su vez también que me traiga los datos de sus tablas relacionadas respectivamente, lo que yo requiero es que la información de las tablas relacionadas este de forma descendente según su category_id, el código que compete en esta ocasión seria este:

```
public function index()
{
    $groups = Group::with('users', 'major', 'course', 'classroom', 'group')
    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
    return Inertia::render('Group/Index')->with([
    'category' => $category
}
<?php
```

El código desde el modelo es el siguiente:

```
class Group extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'course_id',
        'major_id',
        'classroom_id'
    ];

public function evaluationResults()
{
    return $this->hasMany(EvaluationResult::class);
}

public function course()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Course::class);
}

public function classroom()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Classroom::class);
}

public function major()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Major::class);
}

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'group_users');
}
public function group(){
    return $this->hasMany(GroupUsers::class);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tienes varias opciones, un par pueden ser:

- Con eager loading al hacer cada consulta

```php
$groups = Group::with([
    'users' => function ($q) {
        $q->orderBy('category_id', 'desc');
    },
    // 'major' => function ($q) {
])
->get();
```

- Agregarle el orderBy directamente a la relación para todas la consultas

```php
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'group_users')->orderBy('category_id', 'desc');
}
// public function major() ...
```